# How to send local file using Spring Boot Remote Shell (CRaSH)

Tags: linux, spring-boot, putty, scp

I'm using embedded CRaSH shell (`spring-boot-starter-remote-shell` maven dependency) over PuTTY for Spring Boot application running on a Linux system. Is there a way to access/upload local filesystem files from Windows client through the CRaSH shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be - it's not possible, because files cannot be transferred over existing/current SSH session. New SCP session must be initiated for file transfer. In terms of CRaSH shell this means that the files must be copied to the target system prior to executing the commands and then referred to locally.